# ag-grid Pie Chart - change the colors of the slices

Tags: ag-grid

I would like change the colors of the slices in an ag-grid Pie Chart.  Is it possible?  I am using React.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-charts-pie-series/

Comment: Please add code example for what you tried

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, which was actually obvious but I was not correctly looking.  The API reference lists "fills?: string[]".  All set.